# no colour in closing parenthesis in link to reference

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing, citing

In beamer, based on the following code I expect to have the full link to a reference highlighted in red.

```latex
\documentclass[landscape]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\selectlanguage{british}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\textbf{\textcolor{red}{(Cont'd)}}]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    anchorcolor = blue,
    citecolor = red,
    filecolor = blue,
    urlcolor = blue
}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \titlepage
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{aaa}
    \begin{itemize}
        \scriptsize{
            \item ...\cite{jensen_2001}}
    \end{itemize}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliographystyle{jf}
    \tiny\bibliography{references}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However the closing parenthesis remains un-highlighted in red, i.e., let say if the author name is abc and year of publication is 2000, I get abc (2000 highlighted in red but not the closing parenthesis ).
The reference appears as expected in the references slide!
The reference is here:

```
@ARTICLE{jensen_2001,
title = {Value Maximization, Stakeholder Theory, and the Corporate Objective Function},
author = {Jensen, Michael},
year = {2001},
journal = {Journal of Applied Corporate Finance},
volume = {14},
number = {3},
pages = {8-21}}

Here is the content in the jf.sty

% Theorems, etc. (need to load amsthm first)
\newtheoremstyle{jf}% name
{6pt}% Space above
{6pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning normal)

\theoremstyle{jf}

% Make References title all caps.
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}

% Put dots after numbers in section headers.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{1em}}

% Section and table numbers 
\def\thesection       {\Roman{section}}
\def\thesubsection    {\Alph{subsection}}
\def\thetable         {\Roman{table}}

% Section header format
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}{1}{0mm}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}{2}{0mm}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\large\itshape}}

% Put section number back in references to subsections and subsubsections.
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection .}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesection .}

% Appendix formatting:

\def\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%         % Start counting sections again
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}% 
% Use uppercase letters for section numbers:
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}% 
% Number equations (A1), etc.:
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}% 
% Put word "Appendix" before appendix number:
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{Appendix \csname the##1\endcsname}.\hspace{1em}}
% Same formatting as above, but reset equation counter with each section
  \renewcommand{\section}{\setcounter{equation}{0}\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for removing the previous question "No color in closing parenthesis ')' in link to reference"? (seen the text it looks like that this is the same question).

Comment: Iam afraid I could not approve proposed changes

Comment: Interesting: with `article` both parentheses aren't part of the link, with `beamer` only the closing one. There are some related questions on the site but they all involve `biblatex`.

Comment: I couldn't typeset the example (TL-2020). BibTeX fails with `I couldn't open style file jf.bst`.

Comment: With this [`jf.bst`](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/GE_asset_pricing/BGTZ/jf.bst) found on the web, the result is "[1]" and looks ok: "1" is in red colour, "[" and "]" are not part of the link and hence in black.

Comment: @campa Which `jf.bst` did you use for testing?

Comment: @AlexG The same, but TL2017.

Comment: Thus, updating the TeX distro resolves the issue.

Comment: I will edit my question and paste the jf content there.. i think the answer should be in jf.sty

Comment: Thank you all for looking at this!

Comment: As I said, with an up-to-date TeX installation the error disappears. BTW, the example in your question doesn't require `jf.sty` for typesetting. What's missing is a link to the bibliographic style `jf.bst`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex!

Comment: @AlexG have you tried the code and worked for you? I have updated my miktex and it still does not work...

Comment: Weird, two days ago it worked for me (I obtained numeric refs), but today I get the wrong link formatting that you reported. :(

Comment: I have the same problem, though I use apastyle. I am reporting this from a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22 and pdflatex version `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`. Has there been any progress on this?