# Wrong colour for parenthesis in apa-style citation

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I am making a beamer presentation (`Madrid` theme) and using apa-style citations. I noticed that citations are not formatted uniformly, i.e., only one of the parentheses surrounding the year is colored.

[image]

The first is obtained with the \citep{} command and looks Ok to me. The second was obtained with the \cite{} command, but the parentheses are not colored properly.

Why? Which one of the two is colored "wrong"? How do I fix it?

A similar question [was asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574305/no-colour-in-closing-parenthesis-in-link-to-reference), but it was never answered. Here's some code to reproduce

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    pdffitwindow=false,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=,
    citecolor=magenta,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan
}

%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

% ------------  Information on the title page  --------------------
\title[]{\bf{My title}}

\author[]{Me\inst{1}}
\institute[]{Super cool university, Super cool country\inst{1}}
\date[Important conference]{Today}

%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}  % Creates title page

%---------   table of contents after title page  ------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\citep{Hiranuma1999a}
\cite{Hiranuma1999a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \medskip
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the bibliography

```
@article{Hiranuma1999a,
    title = {Syntactic difficulty in {E}nglish and {J}apanese: {A} textual study},
    author = {Hiranuma, So},
    journal = {UCL Working Papers in Linguistics},
    year = {1999},
    volume = {11},
    pages = {309--322}
}
```

Commands for compilation

```
pdflatex main.tex
bibtex main
pdflatex main.tex
pdflatex main.tex
```

I'm working on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. LaTeX was installed with the command

```
$ sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Version of `pdflatex`:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

I also tried with `xelatex` and `lualatex`

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4/dev
Copyright 2021 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 70.1; using 70.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.11.1; using 2.11.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 2.7.4; using 2.7.4
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.1; using 2.13.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134129/36296 works here as well:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    pdffitwindow=false,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=,
    citecolor=magenta,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan
}

%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

% ------------  Information on the title page  --------------------
\title[]{\bf{My title}}

\author[]{Me\inst{1}}
\institute[]{Super cool university, Super cool country\inst{1}}
\date[Important conference]{Today}

\let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\label{#2}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}
\let\oldcite=\cite
\renewcommand\cite[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=magenta} \hyperlink{#1}{\oldcite{#1}}}
\let\oldcitep=\citep
\renewcommand\citep[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=magenta}\hyperlink{#1}{\oldcitep{#1}}}
\let\oldciteauthor=\citeauthor
\renewcommand\citeauthor[1]{\hypersetup{linkcolor=magenta}\hyperlink{#1}{\oldciteauthor{#1}}} 



\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hiranuma1999a,
    title = {Syntactic difficulty in {E}nglish and {J}apanese: {A} textual study},
    author = {Hiranuma, So},
    journal = {UCL Working Papers in Linguistics},
    year = {1999},
    volume = {11},
    pages = {309--322}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}  % Creates title page

%---------   table of contents after title page  ------------
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\citep{Hiranuma1999a}
\cite{Hiranuma1999a}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
    \medskip
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]